# Which PDO parameter data type should I use for mysql blob?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In one of my db tables I have a couple of columns storing encrypted text as BLOB.

So far in my prepared PDO queries i have been binding the values without specifying any PDO data type, something like this :

```
$sql->bindParam(':enc_txt', $enc_txt);
```

Everything works, but I was wondering if it would be better (and possible) to also specify the param type.

Should I use PDO::PARAM_STR ? Or maybe PDO::PARAM_LOB ?

Also, what happens when I don't specify any param type ? Does it default to PARAM_STR or it tries to detect the type automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both should work.
`PDO::PARAM_LOB` allows you to pass a stream but still works fine with a string.
`PDO::PARAM_STR` does the job as well.

I personnaly use `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

More information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php). It may depend on the way you are passing data, and your database's system. TL;DR : Oracle handles things slightly differently.

For your second question, a quick look at the doc [here](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php) indicate `PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default. There is no type guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, everything could be answered from the documentation page

[PDO::PARAM_LOB requires a *file pointer resource*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) while I doubt you are going to save your text into a file only to store it in the database.

The second question is also [answerable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php): PDO::PARAM_STR is the default type when omitted.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), the default `$data_type` is `PDO::PARAM_STR`:

[image]

So you should probably declare it to be `PDO::PARAM_LOB` for blob data.